# How can I upgrade from Drupal 8.0.x to Drupal 8.1.x?

Tags: 8, migrations, upgrading

How can I upgrade from Drupal 8.0.x to Drupal 8.1.x?

Do I have to copy the core files in the project folder and then run update.php as usual, or do I have to do something more complicated like when migrating from older versio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your site installed with composer and want to upgrade to version 8.8.1 you can follow the steps below.

1)cd your_install_dir

2)rm composer.lock

3)rm -rf vendor

4)composer remove webflo/drupal-core-strict --no-update

5)composer remove drupal/core --no-update

6)composer require --dev drupal/core-dev

7)browse yourdomain.com/update.php

8)clear cache if drush installed

congratulations upgradation successful in my case.lets try and please let me know whether it works or not.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, replace the core and vendor directories and run update.php.

**Note:**

> Also please follow the instructions from [upgrade.txt](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!UPGRADE.txt/8). There are several other necessary instruction so that you can recover from any mishappening.

Drupal treats 8.0.x and 8.1.x as 8.x.x.

Comment: That is for the git repository. When you download the archive, you find the vendor directory, with the content updated from the script that makes those archives, the same that adds the timestamp to the .info files of modules.

Comment: Thanks, @kiamlaluno. confirmed and will update the answer.

Comment: Is there any script or automatic way to do fast what is described in upgrade.txt ? Thanks

Comment: I haven't done it before. You can refer this: http://nathan.rambeck.org/blog/8-drupal-upgrade-script . **Before you use this, please check the script and alter as per your needs.**

Comment: It's a shell script and mostly uses drush to do the work.

Comment: You can use drush to update drupal core with a single command 'drush up drupal'. https://drupalize.me/blog/201408/upgrading-drush-work-drupal-8

Comment: @manikandan kannan, if you see the script, it does a lot of thing not just upgrade. it back ups the previous site, database and if upgradation fails it restore to previous site.